# How is this type inferred?

Tags: purescript

Digging through the source:

https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-affjax/blob/v5.0.0/src/Network/HTTP/Affjax.purs#L92

stumbled upon the signature of `get`:

```
get :: forall e a. Respondable a => URL -> Affjax e a
```

and ventured into psci:

```
> import Network.HTTP.Affjax
> :t get
forall e a.
  Respondable a => String
                   -> Aff
                        ( ajax :: AJAX
                        | e
                        )
                        { status :: StatusCode
                        , headers :: Array ResponseHeader
                        , response :: a
                        }
```

Focusing on the tail part of return type, how is:

```
Respondable a =>
{ status :: StatusCode
, headers :: Array ResponseHeader
, response :: a
}
```

matched against `Respondable a` from the first signature -- `a` from `Respondable a => Affjax e a`? Zilch of the instances of `Respondable`:

```
instance responsableBlob :: Respondable Blob where
instance responsableDocument :: Respondable Document where
instance responsableForeign :: Respondable Foreign where
instance responsableString :: Respondable String where
instance responsableUnit :: Respondable Unit where
instance responsableArrayBuffer :: Respondable A.ArrayBuffer where
instance responsableJson :: Respondable Json where
```

matche `Record`. Waat's going on?!

Elucidate the lone rabbit how to dig herself out of similar deep holes in the future. Tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question but I think that your problem rised from the fact that `psci` expands type aliases.
Let's try to do this manually and check if it has done good job. You can find these type aliases in the same file where `get` is defined:

```hs
type Affjax e a = 
  Aff
    (ajax :: AJAX | e)
    (AffjaxResponse a)

type AffjaxResponse a =
  { status :: StatusCode
  , headers :: Array ResponseHeader
  , response :: a
  }
```

So given that `get` has type:

```hs
get :: forall e a
  . Respondable a
  => URL
  -> Affjax e a
```

we can try to substitute all it's aliases. I'm using vertical formatting here for readability. Let's use first alias for `Affjax a e`:

```hs
-- using first alias
get :: forall e a
  . Respondable a
  => URL
  -> Aff
      (ajax :: AJAX | e)
      (AffjaxResponse a)
```

And now second for `AffjaxResponse a`:

```hs
get :: forall e a
  . Respondable a
  => URL
  -> Aff
      (ajax :: AJAX | e)
      { status :: StatusCode
      , headers :: Array ResponseHeader
      , response :: a
      }
```